How can I show postgresql timestamptz columns correctly in excel? (using power query)
I have a column 'created_on' in postgresql database, this column has type timestamptz, and in dbeaver I see the correct dates including the timezone info:

Then I use power query in excel to import this table and column (I do this via an ODBC datasource). But now I see the wrong time:

I expect to see 7:42 but I get 5:42
How can I have the correct timestamps in excel? preferably without creating a new column. The column in the excel table should show 2024-05-17 07:42 without the timezone information.

What does it look like in PQ before you do any transformations (eg at the first or second step)?  Could dbeaver be in a different time zone?
